# Sizing text in markov chain

Tags: r

I have created the markov chain graph but I want to reduce the size of frequency transition numbers that appears on arrows when there is a transition from one state to another.

How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
library(markovchain)
tmA<-matrix(c(0.09,0.01,0.47,0.04,0,0,0,0.04,0.23,0,0.04,0.01,0,0.01,0,0.04,0.02, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.74,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.01,0.06,0,0,0,0.05,0.04,0.2,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.125,0,0,0.125,0.375,0,0.125,0,0.125,0,0.125,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.125,0,0,0.125,0,0.5,0.125,0,0,0,0,0.125,0,0,0,0.25,0.035,0.07,0,0.035,0,0.07,0,0.25,0.11,0.11,0,0.035,0.035,0,0,0,0.575,0,0,0,0.05,0,0,0.15,0,0.075,0.025,0.025,0.05,0.025,0,0,0.025,0.1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.3,0,0.1,0.1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0.15,0,0.15,0,0.1,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0.75,0,0,0,0,0.25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.25,0,0,0.25,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.16,0.17,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.17,0,0,0.25,0.75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.18,0.55,0.667,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.083,0,0,0,0.25), nrow=17,byrow=TRUE)
dtmcA<-new("markovchain",transitionMatrix=tmA,states=c("P","R","ROH","RA","TS","WS","RS","SB","ROP","Pp","T","G","OB","CT","JC","RP","F"),name="markovchain A")
plot(dtmca,edge.arrow.size=0.5)
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for `edge.label.cex`, so e.g. `plot(dtmcA,edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.label.cex=.5)` - see `?igraph::igraph.plotting` for more information.

Comment: improved formatting;